# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Pedido of: Classes.Cliente

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Estou tendo problema em montar uma query no  HQL no Hibernate,olhem o erro que da:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Pedido of: Classes.Cliente [select c from Classes.Cliente c inner join c.Pedido as Pedido]

A query fiz no MySQL é essa mas no Hibernate está dando erro:

```
select cliente.Nome,pedido.Tipo_Servico from cliente join pedido;
```

Qualquer ajuda eu agradeço

Tela da Query

```
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

   List tabela = session.createQuery("select c from Cliente c inner join c.Pedido as Pedido").list();
   for (Iterator iterator = tabela.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
   Cliente clien = (Cliente) iterator.next(); 
  Pedido ped = (Pedido) iterator.next(); 
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) TBL_Orcamento.getModel();
   model.addRow(new Object[]{


   clien.getNome(),
   ped.getTipo_Servico(),

     });

    }
```

Mapeamento do Cliente XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Classes.Cliente" table="cliente" >
  <id name="ID_Cliente" column="ID_Cliente">
      <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
     <property name="Nome" type="string" length ="50" column="Nome" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mapeamento do Pedido XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Classes.Pedido" table="pedido">
  <id name="ID_Pedido" column="ID_Pedido">
      <generator class="native"/>
  </id>    
      <property name="Tipo_Servico" type="string" length ="50" column="Tipo_Servico"/>
      <one-to-one name="clienteID_Cliente" cascade="all"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Classe Cliente

```
package Classes;


public class Cliente {

    private Integer ID_Cliente;
    private String Nome;


    public Cliente(){

    }

    public Cliente(Integer ID_Cliente){
    this.ID_Cliente=ID_Cliente; 

    }


    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String Nome) {
        this.Nome = Nome;
    }

    public Integer getID_Cliente() {
        return ID_Cliente;
    }

    public void setID_Cliente(Integer ID_Cliente) {
        this.ID_Cliente = ID_Cliente;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (ID_Cliente != null ? ID_Cliente.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Cliente)) {
            return false;
        }
        Cliente other = (Cliente) object;
        return !((this.ID_Cliente == null && other.ID_Cliente != null) || (this.ID_Cliente != null && !this.ID_Cliente.equals(other.ID_Cliente)));
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Classes.Cliente{" + "ID_Cliente=" + ID_Cliente + '}';
    }



}
```

Classe Pedido

```
package Classes;


public class Pedido {
    private Integer ID_Pedido;
    private String Tipo_Servico;
    private Cliente clienteID_Cliente;



    public Pedido() {

    }

    public Pedido(Integer ID_Pedido) {
        this.ID_Pedido = ID_Pedido;
    }

      public Integer getID_Pedido() {
        return ID_Pedido;
    }

    public void setID_Pedido(Integer ID_Pedido) {
        this.ID_Pedido = ID_Pedido;
    }

    public String getTipo_Servico() {
        return Tipo_Servico;
    }

    public Cliente getClienteID_Cliente() {
        return clienteID_Cliente;
    }

    public void setClienteID_Cliente(Cliente clienteID_Cliente) {
        this.clienteID_Cliente = clienteID_Cliente;
    }

    public void setTipo_Servico(String Tipo_Servico) {
        this.Tipo_Servico = Tipo_Servico;
    }

     @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (ID_Pedido != null ? ID_Pedido.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Pedido)) {
            return false;
        }
        Pedido other = (Pedido) object;
        return !((this.ID_Pedido == null && other.ID_Pedido != null) || (this.ID_Pedido != null && !this.ID_Pedido.equals(other.ID_Pedido)));
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Classes.Pedido{" + "ID_Pedido=" + ID_Pedido + '}';
    }



}
```

Comment: Sendo "pedido" uma propriedade de "cliente", é provável que esteja em minúsculo. Logo, a query deveria ser *join c.pedido* em vez de *join c.Pedido*. Que tal usar anotação em vez de xml para mapear entidades? Me parece mais simples.

Comment: está tudo como  maiúsculo mesmo

Comment: Escreva o código conforme a convenção do Java que vai te facilitar as coisas. Por exemplo: como a letra maiúscula me chamou atenção demais, eu não notei que o próprio *join* tá errado. Não precisa de join aí se *pedido* é uma propriedade de *cliente*. Basta "navegar" até o pedido, seja na query, seja no consumo das entidades retornadas. Ex: *"...from Cliente c where c.pedido.valorTotal > 100"*. Inclua o código das classes se precisar de mais ajuda. Este é um assunto bem manjado e se não apareceu resposta é porque a pergunta está incompleta.

Comment: é assim que fiz no Mysql a query mas não da certo no Hibernate:


select cliente.Nome,pedido.Tipo_Servico from cliente join pedido;

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ver se fiz mais facil entender

Comment: Coloque suas classes Cliente e pedido.

Comment: Já botei ai as classes agora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As consultas feitas em HQL ou JPQL tem como referência o nome das suas classes, atributos e a relação entre elas. Baseado no relacionamento expresso no seu mapeamento a consulta deveria ser feita dessa forma.

```
SELECT p FROM Pedido p JOIN FETCH p.clienteID_Cliente
```

Tela da Query

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

List<Pedido> pedidos = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pedido p JOIN FETCH p.clienteID_Cliente", Pedido.class).getResultList();
for (Pedido pedido : pedidos) {
    Cliente cliente = pedido.getClienteID_Cliente();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) TBL_Orcamento.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{
        cliente.getNome(),
        pedido.getTipo_Servico()
    });
}
session.close();
```

Observação: Não utilize o método `list()`, ele está marcado como obsoleto. Uso o método `getResultList()`.

Comment: Obrigado,só não entendi porque a query ficou invertendo fazendo a consulta a partir do pedido para o cliente

Comment: ja que no Mysql é do cliente para o pedido

Comment: @DouglasLopes Porque você mapeou dessa forma. Se você olhar suas classes, você perceberá que seu `Pedido` guarda uma referência para o  `Cliente`, ou seja, o `Pedido` sabe o `Cliente` que o fez. Porém, o `Cliente` não tem nenhuma referência para o `Pedido` realizado. Sendo assim, ele não pode te "informar" quais pedidos ele realizou.

Comment: ah,ta mas estranho só seguir o que fiz no mysql e fica bem diferente uma query pra outra